# Query is not running via flask_mysql

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, flask, mysql-python

I am not able to retrieve data from select query as data though stored in variables is not passing values to the the select query

```
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL

@app.route("/loginscr/",methods =['POST'])
def loginscr():

    username = request.form['username']
    password = request.form['password']

    print(request.form.to_dict())
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('Select * from basics where username = %s AND password = %s',(username,password))
    account = cursor.fetchone()
    if account is not None:
        print("Successfull")
    else:
        print("UnSuccessfull")
    return "true"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fetchone()` doesn't return an int. Replace

```
if(account == 1):
```

with

```
if account is not None:
```

or, to be more Pythonic,

```
if account:
```